# Find the frequency of a sum of periodic functions

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

Find the frequency of 
$$y=3\sin(5x)+7\sin\left(55x+\frac{\pi}{16}\right)?$$

How do I find the frequency of this equation?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental period of y(x) is the smallest P such that y(x+P) = y(x) for all x, and the frequency is just the reciprocal of the period. If you graph it, it should be obvious. You can also analyze it algebraically by asking what the maxima of the function are, and what the x distance between them is. You can also use the fact that the period of a sum of functions is a multiple of the fundamental periods of the individual functions. So what are the periods of the individual functions, and what multiples do they have in common?